# osCommerce hacked

Tags: htaccess

I had my osCommerce hacked a few moments ago and the morons are using it to send emails. I have identified that they placed scripts inside osCommerce images directory.

Is there a way to forbid certain directories like those containing images from running scripts using .htaccess or something?

Using simply

```
<Files *.*>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

on .htaccess is not good because images will not appear on the site.

What can I do beyond applying all osCommerce patches to make it stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can drop this into an .htaccess where ever you don't want to allow scripts to execute:

```
<Files *.*>
Options -ExecCGI
</Files>
```

If you know all the "bad" files are named a certain way you could also disable their being associated to a given handler with this:

```
<Files *.*>
RemoveHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
</Files>
```

You can also completely shutdown certain named files with this one from a top level directory:

```
<Directory full-path-to/dir>
     <FilesMatch "\.(php?|pl|perl)$">  
         Order Deny,Allow
         Deny from All
     </FilesMatch>
 </Directory>
```

Or you can lock it down based on the actual URL used to get to it:

```
<LocationMatch "/URL/TO/FILES/.*\.(php?|pl|perl)$">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
</LocationMatch>
```